# Sounds doesn't work

Tags: sound, soundcard

Sound does not work on my computer, neither did it on the other version of Ubuntu. I suspect it is a problem of the sound card, although it worked when using Windows. Anything I can do? Download something?

Answer (score 0):

### Preliminary checks

1. Is your sound system plugged in and switched on?
2. Is your speaker or microphone muted? Check here: [Check for muted speaker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/CheckForMutedSpeakerVolume).

### Advanced troubleshooting

If the **[basic troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Sound_Output_Troubleshooting)** does not help, here are some additional things to try:

- For mixer problems, you can try controlling the [mixers at ALSA level](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer).
- You might be helped by checking if it is a hardware bug that is already fixed upstream. You can try [upgrading your ALSA drivers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa) to the latest snapshot.
- If your problem is audio crackling, glitching, or breaking up, and it is hardware specific, you can try applying a [position fix quirk](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PositionReporting).
- Using very new hardware? [Here's how to check](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/HDAGeneric) whether your built-in sound card has driver support.